# BeautifulSoup - finding sequential (not hierarchical) html elements

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So I am parsing a website that isn't super well designed. Elements aren't really in a hierarchical structure.

There's one enormous div, which has the following structure: A bunch of stuff I don't care about, and then the following structure repeated an arbitrary number of times:

```
h4
p
ul
(
strong
ul
)
```

Where everything between the brackets can be repeated any number of times.

I want to extract every instance of this pattern, but since there's no element containing all of them that I can just select, I'm having trouble. It seems like I need some form of regex-for-elements search, since there is order but no hierarchy.

Alternatively, extracting everything between each h4 would be fine. Is this doable with BeautifulSoup?

Any advice? Is BeautifulSoup even what I want?

Answer (score -1):

```
import bs4


def names(tags):
    return [t.name for t in tags]


def extract(soup):
    all_tags = [c for c in soup.div.children if isinstance(c, bs4.Tag)]

    groups = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(all_tags):
        group = all_tags[i:i + 3]
        if names(group) == ['h4', 'p', 'ul']:
            i += 3
            while True:
                extra = all_tags[i:i + 2]
                if names(extra) == ['strong', 'ul']:
                    group.extend(extra)
                    i += 2
                else:
                    break
            groups.append(group)
        else:
            i += 1
    return groups

# Demo:

print(extract(bs4.BeautifulSoup('''
<div>
    <p></p>

    <h4></h4>
    <p></p>
    <ul></ul>
    <strong></strong>
    <ul></ul>

    <span></span>
    <span></span>

    <h4></h4>
    <p></p>
    <ul></ul>

    <h4></h4>
    <p></p>

    <h4></h4>
    <p></p>
    <ul></ul>
    <strong></strong>
    <ul></ul>
    <strong></strong>
    <ul></ul>

    <span></span>
    <span></span>
</div>
''', 'lxml')))
```